# PHP runs very slow on Windows + DB2

Tags: php, windows, apache, db2, zend-server

I'm working on the optimization of an application. It has some problems of performance. When I was deep in the code, I did not notice any particular problem. The code is a bit dirty but nothing that could cause these performance problems.

I'm wondering how I can improve the system part, which is 'exotic' : Windows + Zend Server + Apache + DB2.

I tried to run an apache benchmark (the php page contains only "echo 'test'"), here is the result :
- ab run from the host : ~400 requests per second
- ab run from another computer : ~0.5 request per second (!) -> I can't explain this very bad performances.

I only found that I must use FastCGI, which I do.

Thanks

Comment: If it runs fast from the host, but slow elsewhere then it sounds like it's something to do with Apache and/or network. Have you tried a single html request? What other things have you tried?

Comment: I don't know why I've got these results for the simple test. Anyway, when I try a "normal page" (with database access), there is no gap. The performances are just poor (for a visualisation page, with a form, on Zend Framework application, I have 5 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Does the host system have anti-virus s/w running?

Or any type of packet sniffing s/w?

If not, it could be a timeout issue with IP reverse lookup or DNS resolve settings in Apache, or in the PHP code, or with the database.

Comment: No antivirus, no firewall, nothing at all. Your hint about the timeout issue is interesting. How could I verify that?